# Limit bandwidth per IP address in Squid

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, bandwidth-control

I am having Squid 3.1.18 installed. I want to limit the maximum bandwidth any IP can use to 128 Kbps. Is it possible using squid ?

I am not using squid authentication so identifying users and setting limit is not an option. Need some way to limit for local IP addresses connecting to squid to access Web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to limit the users based on IP addresses only, you don't need to implementation any authentication. You can use [delay pools](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DelayPools). This will limit the download speed of each IP/subnet according to the configured value(s).

Comment: So you have to compile with --enable-delay-pools option ?

Comment: @nitins: Yes, if you are building from source and it is not enabled by default.